# Xamarin.Forms: Disable iOS picker from "auto picking and closing" when stopped and WAIT for "DONE" button click

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

I am using the regular picker from xamarin.forms:

```
      <Picker 
x:Name="picker_subcat2_mainmenu" 
                                Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                TitleColor="#ffffff"
                                Title=" + "
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                FontFamily="arial"
                                BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                                TextColor="#ffffff"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                VerticalOptions="Center">
                    </Picker>
```

However, this picker has an issue on iOS. 
It contains a long list with elemens, but when you stop scrolling, the picker automatically accepts the item that was highlighted and closes. But this is an issue, since you can only drag your finger up so far. If the list hasnt reached its end yet, it is super finicky getting to the next items (you have to use both fingers to deliver uninterrupted touch).

How can I make the picker close only when the "DONE" button is pressed not and simply by no longer touching it?

THank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Picker Item Selection on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/picker-selection) docs, the `Picker` has 2 types of selection:

> Immediately – item selection occurs as the user browses items in the Picker. This is the default behavior in Xamarin.Forms.
>
> WhenFinished – item selection only occurs once the user has pressed the Done button in the Picker.

In your case you want the second one.

If your code is in xml, you do this:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Picker ... Title="Select a monkey" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished">
          ...
        </Picker>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If your code is in code-behind file:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
...

picker.On<iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
```

Comment: Bravo, my friend. That was epic!

Answer (score 0):

Use this
xmlns:iOSSpecific="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"

And then
<Picker iOSSpecific:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished"